# Android Fatal error "Unable to instantiate Activity"

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I am getting a fatal error in an application that I have been working on. The log file and code is as follows. From what I can tell it is not even getting to the main activity.

Log File:

```
Shutting down VM
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401db760)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{A3.cal/A3.cal.A3Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2366)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2411)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:371)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:108)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:104)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:100)
    at A3.cal.A3Activity.<init>(A3Activity.java:32)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1301)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
    ... 11 more
```

Code:

```
package A3.cal;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class A3Activity extends Activity {
    public int currentMonth = 0;
    private TextView[] dayTableTV = new TextView[6*7]; 
    private Integer[] dayTable = null;
    public Integer currentYear = 0;
    public int firstDayOfWeek = 0;
    public boolean leapYear = false;
    private PopupWindow createEventPopup = null;
    boolean click = false;
    private Button closeAddEventButton = new Button(this);
    private Button submitAddEventButton = new Button(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        makeTable();

        Button addEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addEvent);
        addEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(click == false){
                    addEventPopup();
                    click = true;
                }else{
                    createEventPopup.dismiss();
                    click = false;
                }
            }
        });

        Button nextMonthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextMonthButton);
        nextMonthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               changeMonthNext(getMonth(currentMonth, 1));
            }
        });

        Button previousMonthButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousMonthButton);
        previousMonthButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               changeMonthBack(getMonth(currentMonth, -1));
            }
        });

        closeAddEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createEventPopup.dismiss();
            }
        });

        submitAddEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               submitEvent();
            }

        });

    }
```

There is more code after this, but for saving characters I am not posting it. If you need it please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize your buttons elsewhere, like in `onCreate`.

---

The problem is `this`'s (the `A3Activity`) state  when the `Button` instances are instantiated in the instance variable initializers (`closeAddEventButton` and `submitAddEventButton`).

Instance variable initializers run before constructors, but an object is not completely initialized until its constructor(s) are executed. Objects referenced prior to that will be in an indeterminate state.

*(The state could be determined; I just mean the instance may not be fully-usable yet.)*

Something in the `Button` initialization flow uses an uninitialized value from the `A3Activity` and throws an `NPE`. ([JLS 12.5: Creation of New Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5) details instance initialization process.)

Noting that initializers run in textual order ([JLS 12.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.2)), before constructors, here's a simple demo:

```
public class ThisHere {
    public String aww;
    public String notYet = this.aww;

    GedankenExperiment wat = new GedankenExperiment(this);

    // public class GedankenExperiment {
    //     public GedankenExperiment(thatThere) {
    //         thatThere.aww = ???
    //     }
    // }

    public ThisHere() {
        this.aww = "Hi there";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThisHere thisHere = new ThisHere();
        System.out.println("aww=" + thisHere.aww);
        // > aww=Hi there (initialized in ctor)
        System.out.println("notYet=" + thisHere.notYet);
        // > notYet=null (initialized before ctor)
    }
}
```

---

FYI, the tell-tale sign was this log line:

```
at A3.cal.A3Activity.<init>(A3Activity.java:32)
```

This is the only log line I really saw, because my first step was looking for a reference to anything outside of Android and Java packages. The `<init>` part means it wasn't in a method, so it had something to do with the instance's initializers.

The stack trace included `Button` initializer entries. That plus the use of `this` in their constructors meant that was the only real possibility, hence the quick turn-around without much digging.

Comment: It worked, but why can't I do that, and how would I assign a onClick event to a dynamic button?  --Thanks a million!